# Get chip name of the android device using adb?

Tags: android, adb, android-source

Is there an easy way to get the chip name like the MediaTek SoCs (ARMv5 MT1000 ..) of an Android device using adb shell?

I'm trying to run "adb shell cat system/build.prop" but I don't found the chip or SoC name.

Any Help for that!

Answer (score 4):

To get CPU info of a device via adb try,

`adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: I try that, but it got me the CPU info, I need to know the SoC name, thank you for the answer.

Comment: Yeah, but I think `Hardware` info provided by this command is your requirement. Because I am testing it on `Redmi 4A` that have `Qualcomm MSM8917` chipset and this command is showing perfectly.

Comment: @BillelBmsd..It seems above command is giving chipset info. Is this info not enough to you? What do you mean by Soc?

Comment: Normally on the last line, the chip model is shown. sth like `Hardware        : Qualcomm Technologies, Inc APQ8098`, `APQ8098` means snapdragon 835.

Comment: No such last line for S22+

Answer (score 2):

You will get your soc model number from this you can search it on the Qualcomm product list to find SOC name

```
   adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep hardware
```

In some cases you will directly get your product name

Answer (score 2):

At least on Samsung S8, I get the SoC name (`exynos8895`) by running

```bash
adb shell getprop ro.hardware ro.hardware.chipname
```

Also, I get `samsungexynos8895` from

```bash
adb shell getprop ro.hardware
```